# Arrangements of the word $ABCDEFGGGG$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If we consider the word $ABCDEFGGGG$. To find the number of arrangments for that word, we just calculate: $\frac{10!}{4!}$.

But if now we want to find the total number of arrangements for that word such that $2$ $G$'s must come together and the two other $G$'s be separated. One of the arrangements is for example: $ABGGCDGEFG$.

*Note that the two G's that are separated must also be separated from the other 2'G that are together.

How can we think about this problem?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Do the two $G$'s have to be separated from the separated ones? So for example is the arrangement $BCDEFGGGAG$ valid?

Comment: No in fact the two G's that are separated must also be separated from the other 2'G that are together.

Comment: Arrange the letters `ABCDEF` first.  Next, pick three empty spaces to the left, right, or between those letters already arranged simultaneously and without repetition.  Finally, pick which of those selected spaces receives the two `G`'s and the other spaces each receive one `G`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $G$'s are the annoying part. Do the easy part first! There are $6!$ ways to arrange the letters that are not $G$.

There are then $7$ 'spaces', if we count spots to the extreme left or right of the formed word, for other things. Pick three of them. That gives ${7 \choose 3}$ options. One of them will get the double $G$'s, and there are $3$ choices for this. The other two will get individual $G$'s.

This gives a final tally of $(3)6!{7\choose 3}=75600$ ways to meet the stated requirements.

I counted them all. It's my thing, after all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still did not understand. "if we count spots to the extreme left or right of the formed word, for other things. Pick three of them." What do you mean? can you please just detail your answer step by step? thank you a lot

Comment: There spaces between the letters, I will use - for them: -A-B-C-D-E-F-. Pick three such spaces in which to place your remaining characters, recalling that one of the remaining characters is "GG".

Comment: Jajajaja I understand now. Great answer! anw thank you a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

the answer is not $75600$. The reason is some of the combinations are repeated. 
For example $G G GG$ are separated but when we permute them the first and the second $G$ will make the same combination. So, the solution is $2! * 7C3 * 6!$ .

Comment: The first factor should be $3$ instead of $2!$ because the $GG$ could be in the first, second or third spot chosen for the $G$. By the way, welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: yeah you are right

Comment: You can think about how you have $3 \choose 2$ way to choose the spots for the single $G$'s. That gives $3$ as well. In any case, best to delete an incorrect answer, I'd think. Gusto is good, tho.